# Bootstrap grid system: toggle the class name?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use `col col-md-10` only for an element and want to toggle to `col col-md-12` on a smaller screen, how can I do it with bootstrap?

on load,

```
<div class="col col-md-10">
    <img src="xxx.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
```

so I can get this when I resize the browser smaller,

```
<div class="col col-md-12">
    <img src="xxx.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want :

- a 10-col div on medium (and large) devices
- a 12-col div on small (and extra-small) devices

As Bootstrap 3 is mobile first, use this code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <img src="xxx.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll first set a 12-col size. If the device is up to 992px (aka, if it's a medium device or more), then it'll override the size, and use a 10-col layout.

`.col-md-offset-1` is here to center your image, only on medium/large devices

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/113684)

Comment: thanks for the answer! `col-md-offset-1` does not centerise my picture picture at all for some reason. so  I always have to use this `style="margin:0 auto !important; "` in my image tag.

Comment: Wrap all in a `.container` as in my Bootply, its role is precisely to center your content.